# IE8 iframe reverts to IE7

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-8

It would seem that IE8 automatically reverts to IE7 compatibility mode for content rendered inside an iframe even though the main page renders with IE8 standards. Is there a way make IE8 render all content in IE8 standards? I have tried to use the meta property `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` on both the main page and on the iframed page with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing `X-UA-Compatible` as a HTTP response header; this will theoretically do exactly the same thing as the meta tag you've already tried, but there are differences in how they are handled, and the http header will sometimes work in cases where the meta tag doesn't.

This happens in cases where the browser config is set up specifically to force a particular mode. The preference setting will trump the meta tag, but the http header will trump the preference.

This preference setting is very common in corporate environments, which I guess is what you're working in, given the kind of setup you've described. (I bet they still on Windows XP too, right?)

Comment: You are correct, I am sitting in a corporate enviroment, however the OS is Win7 64. Setting the HTTP response header did not solve the problem for me, IE8 still reverts to some kind of compatibility mode for the content inside the iframe. I will try to test the page with a non-corporate computer and IE8 to see if the issue still persists.